# jQuery div animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs

1. page-left
2. page-right
3. flipper

I have images of equal size in all three divs. I hide the image in flipper div when the document is ready. When I press the animate I use jQuery's animate function to reveal the div. The problem is I want to div the be revealed from right to left and not left to right as show in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/UZWmd/38/

I had solved the problem of revealing from right to left using a single image. But I cannot figure out how to do it in the current scheme of things.

http://jsfiddle.net/UZWmd/38/

Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that effect then you will have to go the opposite way. You're gonna need to hide the top div, instead of revealing (showing) the bottom div. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/UZWmd/46/) modified version of your fiddle.

Comment: I am actually tring to build a flip book. Let us assume we are on page 2 and page 3. When I flip forward I will load page 5 on page-right div and page 4 on the flipper and reveal the flipper from right to left and the same time twen the x position so that it becomes over page-left when the flipping when the flipping is completed. Your solutiuon is elegant. But I cannot use it the given format. I need to reveal the imge from left to right itself. Thats the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/UZWmd/47/

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

[How can I animate the opposite way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552765/how-can-i-animate-the-opposite-way)

Manipulating the margin-left and width on animate seems to do the trick.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it in my fiddle. I tried. But I keep screwing up.